Shared buzzer - algorithm for switching on and off
Question is not about electronics but requires specific experience in building the electronics. I am designing the circuit which would beep with various shapes - on/off durations as well as beep counts.
And this buzzer system may be used by several software applications at the same time. Let's say one will perform two long beeps, another will try 10 short beeps.
I have tried to implement it directly - just concurrently switching the line level, but it causes situations when it is not possible at all to understand what actually is going on.
What would be, in your opinion, right algorithm for shared buzzer for user to at least get an idea what type of beeps may be in there? I have no wish to reinvent bicycle because it was most probably already invented and proven to be effective.

I think you already know the answer:
if you have one actuator, you need to make sure there's no conflicting access to it.
In this case, that means that there can only be one device that defines how things are beeped (because you can't constructively overlay beeps; the device can only beep or not beep, it can't beep twice as loud, or in different frequencies or such).
So, easy solution for a straightforward problem:
Instead of letting each device define its own beeping scheme, they only announce the need to signal something, and a central, single, device connected to the actuator actuates.
This should in fact be easier than even building each device to have its own beeping logic. Instead, you'd just agree on a common bus (here, I²C or plain UART would work, or a SPI daisy chain, or something like CAN, RS-485 or other media if you're building something larger), and when a device wants to signal something, it just sends a message (or replies to a regularly occurring scan) that "hey, here's device nr 3, I've got an alarm with priority A". Then, the central device will take that information and convert it to driving your actuator accordingly.
Now, the logic for doing so is 100% up to your application's needs. But it would seem to me that a sensible mechanism would sort them by importance, and then play only the most important message, or if it's still important to also sound the other alarms, do the alarming, one after the other.
Microcontrollers that have a UART, SPI, and/or I²C interface cost < 1€, things that are comfortable to program for a beginner < 4€. This is the easiest and most cost-efficient solution. One might argue that if you don't want to start synthesizing voice warnings (which by the way is very possible with modern microcontrollers and a speaker instead of a beeper), you're approaching this whole thing incorrectly: you don't want your human that gets a acoustic warning to have to listen closely and figure out what to do. An acoustic warning should be simple. If you need to inform on more than one thing at once, you're using the wrong medium. Here, what I'd recommend is that your central instance just signals one thing (for example, "DANGER!") at once, even when multiple messages come in at once, and that you use a different medium than beeps to communicate the details. Remember, you're doing this because a human, not looking at some display, needs to figure out what's going on with a low probability of error. Put a human in a stress situation and ask them to tell 10 beeps and 7 beeps apart, and they will make mistakes (unless they've been specifically training for this, e.g. as military marine radio operator with Morse training).

I have no wish to reinvent bicycle because it was most probably already invented and proven to be effective.

No need to reinvent the wheel, indeed!

The right thing probably is to simply use signalling lines and diodes, and only use a constant single signal for everything, in combination with LEDs or other media. A factory owner doesn't want their staff to figure out whether someone fell into the machinery or whether it's lunchtime based on a count of beeps.
If you do need a complex acoustic signalling scheme, there's devices for that, they're microcontrollers, and you should have exactly one connected to your buzzer that reacts to status info from the other devices in a "sensibly defined" manner. Microcontrollers clearly are the common way to solve such finite-state machine problems.

